# How to get rid of the additional line in <textarea> element

Tags: html, textarea

When display the same content in textarea element and pre element, the results will be different. textarea has one more line than pre.

```
<textarea>Hello</textarea>
<pre>Hello</pre>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/45XkC/

That means, if I save the content in textarea and reload it in textarea again, it will always one more line compare to the previous version.

How can I get rid of the additional line in text area to make the display the same as pre element?

Updated: the content is not fixed, and the textarea is re-sizable. The question is equals to Why there is an additional line in textarea than pre, and is there any way to get rid of  it in front-end?

Comment: Since the `<textarea>` contents are being saved and loaded via AJAX, you need to add the details about how this is being handled. Are you sure the save and reload is not adding a carriage return somewhere? A demo would also make this easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your continuously reply. I think there is nothing wrong with the AJAX. I have updated the question to be more clear, but can't create a demo currently.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `rows` attribute like

```
<textarea rows="1">Hello</textarea>
```

will instruct the browser to render just 1 row.

Comment: I need change and save the content of the textarea, but when I reload, it will always one more line than the previous version.

Comment: How are you saving and reloading the `<textarea>` content? How is the `<textarea>` value being set?

Comment: Saving using Ajax and reloading when refresh the page. Does it matter to set the value of the textarea instead of the content?

Comment: Sorry I meant the _contents_. Is the `<textarea>` contents sent via AJAX correct? Are the contents being persisted correctly?

Comment: Yes, the contents display correct in <pre>, but will have an additional line in <textarea>. That means save <textarea>hello</textarea> will because "hello\r\n", after reload will become <textarea>hello\r\n</textarea>, etc.

Comment: You should trim the `<textarea>` _contents_ (remove whitespace from the start and end) before saving it to where ever you are saving it to. Could be done in JavaScript - see [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) or whatever language is processing the AJAX POST before saving the data.

Comment: The quick way to solve my coding problem is to use JavaScript. However, to ask this question, I wonder if there is any explanation of why there is an additional line in textarea element, so I can solve the problem according to the basic design for textarea. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: To answer that I'd have to see how you are getting the value from the `<textarea>`, how it is being serialized and POSTed via AJAX and how it is being received by the server and how it is saved in the database. I am guessing that at one point an extra carriage return is being added :-)

Comment: It seems '\n' will show one more line in <textarea> than <pre>, it works when I remove the '\n' at the end of the contents. Cheers.